# Include gstreamer in qt .pro for windows

Tags: windows, qt, gstreamer, qmake

I'm trying to link a gstreamer, but constantly getting an undefined reference to a different functions gstreamer. GSTREAMER _1_0_ROOT_X86_64 exist in environment variable and path is correct

```
GSTREAMER_PATH=$$(GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86_64)
INCLUDEPATH = $${GSTREAMER_PATH}/include/gstreamer-1.0
INCLUDEPATH += $${GSTREAMER_PATH}/include/glib-2.0
INCLUDEPATH += $${GSTREAMER_PATH}/lib/glib-2.0/include
INCLUDEPATH += $${GSTREAMER_PATH}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include

LIBS = $$files($${GSTREAMER_PATH}lib/*.lib, true)
```

Comment: Doesn't your platform have `pkg-config`?  We normally write `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0)` and `LIBS += $(shell pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0)`.

Comment: I used pkg-config under linux and all worked, but if I use it under windows then it can not find the gstreamer.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to link?